# laravel 6 when login go to previous url not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-route

I'm using Laravel `framework` my previous version of laravel is 5.8
and in my middleware login

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    else
    {
        Session::put('url.intended',URL::previous());
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

and this is the controller login controller

```
if(Session::get('url.intended') <> '')
    return Redirect::to(Session::get('url.intended'));
else
    return redirect('/');
```

with this codes in laravel 5.8 everything was working great but when i upgrade to laravel 6 its not working any more i dont know why 
any help here thanks 
if i came from any link its always redirect me to / link

Comment: the authentication middleware and login controller handle all of this fine without any modification ... any reason you are using a custom middleware and controller ?

Comment: no there is not

Comment: well `Url::previous` can return a url to `'/'` if it can't find a referer or a previous url set in the session ... there isn't always a previous url in this regard

Comment: i echo Url::previous its always give me login page thats is the last url not the real previous url

Comment: you echo `Url::previous` where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably be letting the framework handle as much of this as possible. If you must use your own middleware and Controller method still let the framework handle this as it does best.

Dealing with the intended URL is already something the framework is capable of doing itself and checks multiple conditions to figure this out. You can use the `guest` method of the Redirector to have it do this for you:

```
return redirect()->guest('login');
```

This will take care of the redirect to 'login' and set the `url.intended` in the session as needed.

After login is successful you can redirect them to where they were trying to end up, 'intended', or a fallback url:

```
return redirect()->intended('/');
```

This will redirect to what it can find as the 'intended' and if not use a fallback. It will also remove the `'url.intended'` key from the session as it is no longer of use. No need to set or check the session yourself.